# Tables thead , tbody and tfoot

Tags: html, html-table

HTML5 if I have a table with a header and table rows, do I need to use the thead, tbody and tfoot tags?
Can also have a class on a td or is it better to use a span?
below is how I have been doing it, but I have some doubts.

```
        <table class="table-myTable">
        <caption>Courseware Production Status</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                    <th>C</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="myClass">3</td>
                </tr>
       </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You have the right to not use `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, or `<tfoot>`.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element:concept-element-content-model) If you choose to not use a `<tbody>` for your `<tr>`s, [one will be created for them by the browser engine](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element:dom-table-rows-3). Proof:

```css
td:before {
  content: 'bare td';
}

tbody td:before {
  content: 'inside a tbody';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use classes with any element. If the class applies to *an entire cell*, put it on the `<td>`. If it applies specifically to *the text within the cell*, use a `<span>` or, preferably, one of the many more [semantic elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Text_content).